# How to store upperbound to infinite DecimalRangeField

Tags: django, postgresql, infinite

from django.contrib.postgres.fields import DecimalRangeField
Django3 and Postgres11

I need to store `inf` in the `DecimalRangeField()`

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import DecimalRangeField
from psycopg2.extras import NumericRange

class Premium(models.Model):
     sum_insured = DecimalRangeField()
```

`NumericRange` with small number is work

```
    def test_range_field(self):
        Premium.objects.create(
            sum_insured=NumericRange(3, 12),
        )
        self.assertEqual(1, Premium.objects.count())
```

**Problem:**

```
Premium.objects.create(
   sum_insured=NumericRange(3, float('inf'))
)
```

It raises error

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "Infinity"
```

**Question:**
How do I store the `inf` in the `DecimalRangeField`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [**`NumericRange`** object](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.NumericRange) is a special form of a [**`Range`** object](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.Range). As the documentation specifies for the `lower` and `upper` parameters:

> `lower` – lower bound for the range. **`None` means unbound**
>
> `upper` – upper bound for the range. **`None` means unbound**

If the `lower` or `upper` is set to `None` (for example by not specifying it), you define an interval where the `lower` or upper goes to infinity respectively.

So you can define this with:

```
Premium.objects.create(
   sum_insured=NumericRange(3, None)
)
```

or shorter:

```
Premium.objects.create(
   sum_insured=NumericRange(3)
)
```